# exec() on remote server returns only return-var 1 | 7 ways tried without success

Tags: php, c, apache, .htaccess

On remote apache (firstly `PHP Version 5.3.29` | finally updated to 7.04 without safe mode enabled) i've tried to run a tiny 20 chars c-file "ccc" with

```
 exec(), popen(), shell_exec(), system(), passthru(), backtick
```

... where 5 of 6 approaches are with local success, 0 of 6 so far with remote.

I get a return value "1" in 3 of 6 cases (`passthru, exec, system`), and an empty (?) stream (if that is possible) with `popen` (see below).

`exec(), passthru(), system()` are willing run commands like ls on remote server, but give me nothing with ccc, the c-testfile with only `printf("c did");`) in it.

The server is configured (php-ini) after upgrade to `php-Version 7.04` without safe-mode.

My file exec.php only tries to run ccc in 6 ways (shortened below)

```
// start source

error_reporting(E_ALL); 

echo exec ('ls', $out0, $error0);

$popen = popen ($cpath.'ccc', 'r'); 
stream_get_contents ( $popen ); 

shell_exec ($cpath.'ccc');

passthru ($cpath.'ccc', $error3);

exec ($cpath.'ccc', $out4, $error4);

system ($cpath.'ccc', $error5);

$output = `$cpath.ccc`; 

echo '20160316 errors 0-6 | 0: '.$error0.' |  3: '.$error3.' | 4: '.$error4.' | 5: '.$error5.'<br/>';   
echo '20160316 outputs 0-6 | 0: '.gettype($out0).' | 1: '.get_resource_type($popen).' | 4: '.gettype($out4).';  

// end source
```

The file does open the c-file without errors on local server,
but without output and with return 1 on remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the c-file, what is not a provided feature of that hoster.
If changing the given path of executables (in $cpath) to path obtained by exec(pwd), and changing type c-file to type perl-file, AND deleting .htaccess out of directory, then execution is correct.

Comment: When trying to execute a c-file under the updated conditions, the host returns a code "137".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the C program is only local. The program must be on the remote server. Also the apache service must have read and execute permission to it.

Comment: The C programm ccc is on remote server (see ls):js
ccc
ccc.c
css
exec.php
img
inc
index.php

Comment: The php-ini shows what is permitted or not:  ... '--enable-safe-mode=yes' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-fastcgi' '--with-exec-dir=/opt/RZphp5/exec'  '--disable-force-cgi-redirect'  Is there anything i can do? i so far tried everything i found.

Comment: the errors on remote server are 20160316 errors 0-6 | 0: 0 | 3: 1 | 4: 1 | 5: 1, on local server (if any) errors 0-6 | 0: 0 | 3: 5 | 4: 5 | 5: 5. is my provider to strict in safe mode? is there a way for example by htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the php-version to a level above 5.4 could be an answer. Safe mode then should be turned of. That is, exec(), popen(), shell_exec(), system(), passthru() should not be blocked by php-ini-restrictions any more.

Comment: Having just upgraded php from 5.3 (above) to 5.5, then 5.6, finally 7.0 didn't fix the issue. exec(), popen(), shell_exec(), system(), passthru() won't run the c-command ccc with more output than return_var value 1 !